# Calculation between groups in one column in tidy data

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data like that:

```
df <- (
      tibble(
      ID = rep(1:2, 4),
      Group = c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B", "A", "B"),
      Parameter = c("Blood", "Blood", "Height", "Height", "Waist", "Waist", "Hip", "Hip"),
      Value = c(6.3, 6.0, 180, 170, 90, 102, 60, 65))
      )
```

I want to calculate the ratio between "Height" and "Waist" and between "Waist" and "Hip".

I have the following solution. But my solution requires using spread() and delivers only the calculation for "Waist-to-hip".

```
     df <- rbind(df,
        spread(df, Parameter, Value)
        %>% transmute(ID = ID,
                      Group = Group,
                      Parameter = "Ratio.Height-to-Hip",
                      Value = Height / Hip,
                      Parameter = "Ratio.Waist-to-Hip",
                      Value = Waist / Hip))
```

Is it possible to stay in tidy data format and avoid switching to the long-format? Why is the calculation for "Height-to-hip" missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one the possible solution:

```
# Calculate ratios "Height" vs "Waist" and "Waist" vs "Hip"

# 1. Load packages
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# 2. Data set
df <- tibble(
   id = rep(1:2, 4),
   group = c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B", "A", "B"),
   parameter = c("Blood", "Blood", "Height", "Height", "Waist", "Waist", "Hip", "Hip"),
   value = c(6.3, 6.0, 180, 170, 90, 102, 60, 65))

# 3. Filter and transform data set
df <- df %>% 
  filter(parameter %in% c("Height", "Waist", "Hip")) %>% 
  spread(parameter, value)

# 4. Convert column names to lower case
colnames(df) <- tolower(colnames(df))

# 5. Calcutate ratios
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    ratio_height_vs_waist = round(height / waist, 2),
    ratio_waist_vs_hip = round(waist / hip, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the data are not in a tidy format.

Two key features of the tidy format are ([Wickham, 2013](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10)):

1. Each variable forms a column;
2. Each observation forms a row.

In its original format, your data violates these two rules. For example, the *Parameter* column contains four variables (Blood, Height, Waist, and Hip). The knock-on effect of grouping several variables within *Parameter* is that each observation has to be repeated across several rows. In general, repeated rows of an identifier (*ID* in this case) in the absence of repeated measures is a sign that two or more variables have been grouped under a single column.

Anyway, here's my attempt to clean the data (I have used mutate and and not transmute for illustrative purposes).

```r
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr) # For the %<>% function, which I love

# Make data frame, df
df <- tibble(
        ID = rep(1:2, 4),
        Group = c("A", "B", "A", "B","A", "B", "A", "B"),
        Parameter = c("Blood", "Blood", "Height", "Height", "Waist", "Waist", "Hip", "Hip"),
        Value = c(6.3, 6.0, 180, 170, 90, 102, 60, 65))

# Wrangle df
df %<>% 
    # ID and Group appear to be repeated, so use them to group_by
    group_by(ID, Group) %>%
    # Spread the Value column by the Parameter column
    spread(key = Parameter,
           value = Value) %>%
    # Ungroup, just because its a good habit
    ungroup() %>%
    # Generate new columns.
    mutate(Ratio_height_to_hip = Height / Hip,
           Ratio_waist_to_hip = Waist / Hip)

# Print df
df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#>      ID Group Blood Height   Hip Waist Ratio_height_to_hip
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>
#> 1     1     A   6.3    180    60    90            3.000000
#> 2     2     B   6.0    170    65   102            2.615385
#> # ... with 1 more variables: Ratio_waist_to_hip <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df %>%
  spread(Parameter, Value) %>%
  mutate("Ratio.Height-to-Hip" = Height / Hip) %>%
  mutate("Ratio.Waist-to-Hip" = Hip / Waist) %>%
  gather("Parameter", "Value", -c("ID", "Group"))
```

Your data is not in tidy format ;) If you want your data in tidy format remove the last step.